# Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/html, but no tag was defined for name: inputFile

Tags: jsf, maven, file-upload, jsf-2.2

I am really stumped by this problem.  We have richfaces project.  I wanted to use the  tag instead of the  because I didn't like the way the files were being passed to the bean. Our project works very well.  I believe I have all of the needed depedencys in the POM, but I even manually added a few after reading this by [How to setup project to support h:inputfile in JSF 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671025/how-to-setup-project-to-support-hinputfile-in-jsf-2-2) @BalusC so I added

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
<artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
<version>1.2_15</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
<groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
<artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
<version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is my page:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:b="http://richfaces.org/sandbox/bootstrap"
    template="/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="metadata">
    </ui:define>



    <ui:define name="content">

    <h:inputHidden id="active-bean-name" value="dataloader" />

    <h:form>

    <h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <rich:fileUpload></rich:fileUpload>

    <h:inputFile id="file" value="#{DataLoaderBean.file}"/>
     <h:commandButton value="Upload"
      action="#{DataLoaderBean.upload}"/>
    </h:form>

    </h:form>

    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're clearly specifying Maven coordinates for JSF 1.2 impl and JSF 2.1 API and then you're complaining that you didn't get JSF 2.2 features. I'm not sure what's unclear here. Just set Maven coordinates to JSF 2.2? If your concrete problem is that you can't figure what they are, just look at JSF homepage: http://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html

Comment: @BalusC you are right, that was pretty stupid of me. We are using JBOSS AS 7.1.  I dropped the files in because I was confused, but jsf-api and jsf-impl are packaged with JBOSS AS 7.1.  Problem is I can't upgrade to 2.2 because JBOSS AS 7.1 doesn't support it.  Only JBOSS AS 8 which we are not ready for.  So I think I am SOL.  Thanks for the help as always.

Comment: You can definitely upgrade JBoss AS 7.1 to utilize JSF 2.2. Others have done it before you. See e.g. https://community.jboss.org/thread/203257. Perhaps you got confused because it by default already ships with 2.1 out the box? Or perhaps you didn't realize that you shouldn't be doing this via Maven because JSF is not bundled in webapp, but in server itself?

Comment: @BalusC yes, at first I was confused that I shouldn't be doing it with Maven, because it was bundled. Then I did attempt to upgrade to 2.2 utilizing the steps above, but hit several errors.  I then read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138490/jsf-2-2-final-not-works-on-jboss-7-1-1 and this is what led me to believe that I could not upgrade, but I did not read the post carefully enough.  I will attempt to upgrade again and see how it works.  Thank you!

Comment: @BalusC you are the man, I was missing one line when I tried to upgrade to 2.2.  I didn't realize that  jsf-api now depends on jsf-impl.  That is now resolved and I am good to go.