# JSF can't find h:inputFile tag

Tags: maven, jsf, jsf-2

I try to reproduce this tutorial http://www.javatutorials.co.in/jsf-2-2-file-upload-example-using-hinputfile/ and I have a big problem: inputFile tag is not available for me.

```
<h:form id="inputForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Upload File
    <h:inputFile id="file"
                 label="file"
                 value="#{inputBean.part}"
                 required="true"
                 requiredMessage="File not selected !!">
    </h:inputFile>
    <h:message style="color: red" for="file" /><br />

    <h:commandButton id="submit"
                     action="#{inputBean.uploadFile}"
                     value="upload file" /><br />
    <h:outputText value="#{inputBean.statusMessage}"
                  rendered="#{not empty inputBean.statusMessage}" />
</h:form>
```

I've seen question [Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/html, but no tag was defined for name: inputFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898819/tag-library-supports-namespace-http-java-sun-com-jsf-html-but-no-tag-was-def), but in my pom file correct file version are used (2.2.7 > 2.2.4)

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is my project^ https://github.com/Solorad/CheckRulesServer

Comment: you have added the namespace at the top of your xhtml page? I.e. <html    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" ...... > ?

Comment: Yes, I just copied page from tutorial

Comment: Your project just works fine with me, I just changed java version in pom.xml to 1.7 and eveything is Ok

Comment: Does it upload file correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found! In .xhtml file I imported wrong tag library. 
I should used instead.
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"